# How to recreate a merged Git branch

Tags: git

Let's assume a feature branch was deleted after it was merged to master.

A few days/weeks later, I have a need to generate patch files for all the commits that were in that feature branch.

If I had the feature branch around, I could use the following command to generate patches:

```
git format-patch $(git merge-base master my_feature_branch)..my_feature_branch
```

So, how could I re-create the feature branch so I can use the above command?

Comment: kind of an unusual problem; so you *know* that you need to hand someone a patch that describes everything that happened in that branch, but you can't remember when that started?

Comment: Do you want to know how to *find* the commit that was the latest commit in the feature branch, or how to *create a branch* on that commit once you have found it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, first, branches don't really get deleted.  Only branch *names* get deleted.  But this gets us into a thorny question: [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)

Let's take a fast look at the process of merging.  We start with a series of commits in the *commit graph* (or "DAG"; see the linked question) that look like this:

```
...--o--*-----o   <-- master
         \
          o--o--o--o--o   <-- feature
```

We then run:

```
git checkout master
git merge feature
```

which somehow figures out what we've changed in both `master` and `feature` since the last time we merged them (which was actually never, but they were together at one time, at the point marked `*` here).  Git then makes a new *merge commit* that points back to both of these branch tip commits:

```
...--o--*-----o---------o   <-- master
         \             /
          o--o--o--o--o   <-- feature
```

and we have "a merge": a commit, of type *merge commit*.

We can now erase the word `feature` and the arrow, i.e., remove the *name*.  The *graph* remains intact, retained by the name `master`:

```
...--o--*-----o---------M   <-- master
         \             /
          o--o--o--o--F
```

Should we wish to see what went into `master` via `feature`, all we have to do is find the commit I have labeled `F` (for Feature) here.  Note that I have also labeled the merge commit `M` (for merge).

The way to find it is to start from `master` and work backwards until we find `M`.  (It's right there at the tip of `master` right now, although later, it will be some number of steps back from the tip.)  Then, we simply look at the *second parent commit* of `M`.

To find the second parent of a commit whose hash ID we know, we just tell Git: *tell me the hash ID of the second parent of this other hash ID.*  The easy way to do this is with `git rev-parse`.  Let's say the hash ID of `M` is `badf00d`:

```
git rev-parse badf00d^2
```

Git spits out the full hash ID of `F`.  The hat-two suffix means "second parent" (hat-one, or just hat by itself, means "first parent").

Now we may also want to find commit `*`.  That's the *merge base* of the commit that is the *first* parent of `M`, and this particular commit `F` that we just found.  To find the merge base of two commits, we ask Git:

```
git merge-base badf00d^1 badf00d^2
```

We can then look at every commit in the range starting just after the merge base `*` and going up through and including commit `F`, using `git log` or `git format-patch` or whatever.

We can do this with the raw hashes, or we can point names (temporary or permanent, they will live exactly as long as you like) to commits `M`, `F`, and/or `*`, using `git branch` or `git tag`.  Each name remembers the hash ID for you.  The chief difference between a tag name and a branch name is that if you `git checkout` a tag name, you get a "detached HEAD" and are not on a branch, but if you `git checkout` a branch name, you get on that branch, and if you make *new* commits, they will cause that branch to advance:

```
$ git branch newname <hash-ID-of-commit-F>

...--o--*-----o---------M--o--o--o   <-- master
         \             /
          o--o--o--o--F   <-- newname

$ git checkout newname
... hack away ...
$ git commit ...

...--o--*-----o---------M--o--o--o   <-- master
         \             /
          o--o--o--o--F--o   <-- newname (HEAD)
```

This is all that branches are, in Git: the *names* just point to commits, while the branch *structure*, the history or DAGlet or whatever name you want, is formed by the permanent parts of the commit DAG.  Branch names have the special feature that you can `git checkout` them and make them advance by running `git commit`.

Comment: Very useful info.  I understood various commands involved in finding commits in a merged branch.  So far I have used either the IDE or 'tig' to find them.  The tools that are widely used in the organization require a branch name as the input.  Seems like one option is to write a script that will find commits F and *(taking M as the input), create a branch from * and cherry pick the range between * and F (inclusive).  I would have been nice if the branch command supported an option to create a branch this way :) thanks

Comment: Incidentally, it's not at all clear to me why you would want to re-copy the commits leading to F. You can just make a new branch name pointing to commit `F`, check out the new branch by name, and make new commits on that branch.

Comment: legacy tools.  They use git merge-base between given branch and master to generate patch for all commits in the branch.  Creating a branch off F would not return * as the merge base.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume the following simplified history: The feature branch was based on commit `N` and contained the commits `P` and `Q`. In the meantime, commit `O` was added to the master branch. The feature branch was merged in commit `R`. After that, commits `S` and `T` were created, which is where master is now.

```
M -- N -- O -- R -- S -- T [master]
      \       /
       P --- Q
```

You want to find commit `Q`. I don't think there is a programmatic way to do this, so you need to use any repository browser, for example `gitk`.

Once you have found `Q`, you can easily recreate the feature branch:

```
$ git branch my_feature_branch <hash of commit Q>
```

I'm not sure if you are aware of this, but a key to understanding this is knowing that a branch is not much more than a "pointer" or "bookmark" to a commit.

Comment: Won't work. Refer to this image: http://imgur.com/a/0DL9l - merge base for 'my-feature-branch' there is 4fa54c2f300a6c7b0056568270c153b215d5b8d8 vs 46436103594f6bc35ce1106fc09fd702011b08ad for 'new-my-feature-branch' which is created from the commit ID as you suggested.

Comment: @akirekadu That's because you've recreated a different situation there. Note the `Fast-forward` when you merged. In the end you have a plain linear history `A - B - C - D` with `master` on `D` and `new_my_feature_branch` on `C`.

Comment: To create a real merge commit when fast-forwarding would be possible, use `git merge --no-ff`.

Comment: Sure, there will be a merge commit if you use '--no-ff'.  Our CI system does not do that.  Let's say we can change it.  Still merge base will be different for 'my_feature_branch' and 'new_my_feature_branch'.  Try it out..

Comment: After reading @torek's answer I understand that what you proposed is a pointer in the right direction.  His post offers all the info required to resurrect the feature branch in question, so decided accept that one.  Than you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a base commit, the one from which the now-deleted feature branch had diverged, you can proceed like follows -

1. Check out a branch based off the base commit.
2. Using `git cherry-pick`, cherry-pick the merge commit that had merged the feature branch into master. If this doesn't work, you can cherry-pick individual commits that were part of the feature branch.